# Left and Inner Join difference... once forever

Tags: sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I know that many threads has been created here & on the internet about this topic. But I really can't get the final point on the difference between the two statements! I mean, trying and trying I can reach all the results I need with my queries, but I really don't have full control of the knife!

I'm considering myself a very good programmer and a very good SQL-ista and I feel a little ashamed about this...

Here's an example:

- I have a table with the pages of a website ("web_page")
- a table with the categories ("category").
- a category can contain one or more pages, but not vice versa
- a category may contain NO pages at all
- a page can be visible or not in the website

So if I want to show all the categories and their pages, I mean both categories with pages and without, I have to do something like this:

```
FROM category
LEFT JOIN web_page ON ( web_page.category_id = category.category_id AND web_page.active = "Y" )
```

So if a category has no pages, I'll see web_page_id NULL on the record of that category.

But if I do:

```
FROM category
LEFT JOIN web_page ON ( web_page.category_id = category.category_id )
...
WHERE web_page.active = "Y"...
```

I'll select only the categories that have at least one web_page... But WHY?

This was just an example... I'd like to understand once forever this difference!

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make your query to work as you intended, put the condition into the `ON` clause:

```
FROM category
LEFT JOIN web_page ON web_page.category_id = category 
   and web_page.active = "Y"
```

The reason this works is (with most databases, but not all) the `WHERE` clause filters the rows *After* they are joined. If the join doesn't result in a web page row joining (because the category had no web pages), then all the columns of web page will be `null`, and any comparison of a value (like `"Y"`) to a `null` is false, so those non-joining rows will be filtered out.

However, by moving the condition into the `ON` clause, the condition is executed *as the join is made*, so that you only *join* rows that are `active = "Y"`, but if there aren't any such rows, you'll just get the left join `null` web page.

This version of the query is really saying: "give me all categories and their *active* web pages (if any)"

Note that I said "most databases"... mysql for example is smart enough to understand what you are trying to do, and your query will work as you intended if run on mysql.

Comment: +1 to this answer. Thanks. I always wonder which of JOIN or WHERE works first.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because SQL is being processed in stages:

1. `FROM` clause (all joins are here);
2. `WHERE` clause;
3. `GROUP BY` clause;
4. Window functions (not related to the MySQL though);
5. `ORDER BY` clause.

So this really is important, if you want to *filter* on `web_page.active='Y'` or you want to *join* with the same condition. In the former case, join is done and you just filter out the results, converting you `OUTER` join into the `INNER` one. In the latter case, you will achieve the desired result, as non-matching rows will result in `NULL` values for the corresponding columns.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to help you on the understanding part.

Consider is a facet of the SQL Language that when the criteria is specified within the `LEFT JOIN`, it applies when finding the records to match against. 
When the criteria is specified in the WHERE clause at the bottom, it applies to all of the records - after the join has occured. This has an unintended side effect of changing the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN` as you have seen.

You can get around this by doing a `WHERE` clause like this:

```
WHERE COALESCE(web_page.active,"Y") = "Y"
```

But that isn't actaully guarenteed to be the same results, so the proper way to do it is to keep that criteria in the `ON` clauses of the `JOIN`.