# Conditions in WHERE clause and in ON clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume I have two tables,

```
   Student                           Test

Id    Name                   TestId   Type  StudentId
--    ----                   ------   ----  --------- 
1     Mark                     774    Hard     1  
2     Sam                      774    Hard     2 
3     John                     775    Easy     3
```

Now I have to find those students(the student id,name and testid) who have taken "hard" type of test in MySql.

Which one is better(In terms of performance)?.

```
1.Select student.id,student.name,test.testid 
  from student 
  join test 
  on test.studentid=student.id and test.type='hard'

2.Select student.id,student.name,test.testid 
  from student 
  join test 
  on test.studentid=student.id 
  where test.type='hard'
```

May I know the reason?**(Assume there are millions of students and million types of tests)**

Comment: If you run the query through an analyzer, what are the differences in the execution plans?  (Side question... Is `Test` really many-to-one with `User`?  Maybe I don't know your domain, but I would think there would be a finite number of Test entities and a finite number of User entities and a many-to-many relationship between the two.  Are there really *millions* of *unique* Test entities?)

Comment: @David yes it is a many-to-many relationship,but my example doesn't show it...Yes,may be i have exaggerated a bit by saying millions of unique entities.But the reason I said there are many unique test types is that I thought for few unique entities,both the queries have same performance but for large no. of entities,the difference may be huge.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329683/left-and-inner-join-difference-once-forever/11329759)

Comment: @vyegorov please read the question properly...I am not talking about left outer join.I also know that where clause executes after join...I only wanted to know the performance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are same but with *different performance*. I recommend to you use `EXPLAIN PLAN` for queries if you want to choose query with *better performance*.

Have look at [Understanding the Query Execution Plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html).

Also you can improve your queries with `INDEXES` for columns which you are using the most frequently in `WHERE` clause, you can have look at relational algebra also.

Comment: Yes I wanted to use explain plan but I can run queries as a web service.(i.e I type the query and when I click run,a web service is called which returns the result).So i do not have access to explain plan. Also,I have only 100 odd records.So difference in performance won't be much.

Comment: you can create local database, create and fill up tables then create statements which you will use and test them which one makes the best performace.

Comment: @kannan: "Also,I have only 100 odd records.So difference in performance won't be much." If the difference won't be much, why do you care which is faster?

Answer (score 0):

Those queries are exactly the same and should have exactly the same query plan. It is unlikely that there will be any measurable difference in execution time.

There will however be a difference if you change `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`. In that case you need to use the first version. The second version will not give the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Performance-wise these two are about the same.  You can verify that by using the EXPLAIN command.

So the question becomes one of clarity of expression of your data model.  It may seem like angels dancing on the head of a pin.  But, if you're pulling all the test results with your JOIN commmand, and then asking for a subset, go with `WHERE type='hard'`.

But if, conceptually, you're pulling only the hard ones, then go with the `ON` formulation.

Notice that these two will work differently if you use `LEFT JOIN`. You'll get a row for each student that hasn't ever taken a hard test, as well as a row for each hard test each student has taken if you use the `ON` formulation with `LEFT JOIN`.